# shell - cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to get the output of the command line arguments in reverse order. But I am getting a error while doing so.

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=$@
len=$#
space=" "
echo "No. of arguments = $len"
echo "Entered arguments = $str"
while [ $len -ne 0 ]
do
        tmp=`echo $str | cut -d " " f $len`
        rev=$rev$tmp$space
        len=`expr $len - 1`
done
echo "Arguments in reverse = $rev"
```

And when I run the script, I get this error :

```
robin@robin-VirtualBox:~/lx$ ./s1.sh one two three
No. of arguments = 3
Entered arguments = one two three
cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
Arguments in reverse =
```

Comment: [Wha...](http://askubuntu.com/questions/456693/shell-and-bash-different-errors)

Comment: @Seth I am sorry, I had to. It was all a mess.

Comment: Well you could have just edited it, but ok :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are just missing the `-` sign before your `-f` argument to `cut`.  I was able to run your script and have it function properly after making that one modification.

Comment: LOL! I didn't saw that. Now, its working fine. Thank you!